# docker-compose with /dev/ttyUSB - permission after restart

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file to pass USB into the docker, it works so far and looks like this:

```
container.services:
  sam-container:
    image: xyz
    device_cgroup_rules:
      - 'c *:* rmw'
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
      - $HOME/.Xauthority:/node/.Xauthority:rw
      - /etc/fonts:/etc/fonts
      - ./config_persist:/app/config_persist
      - /dev:/dev
      - user-volume:/home/node/
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
    user: "1000:1000"
    group_add:
      - dialout
    command: npm start
```

The problem is, if I reboot the host - the application has no permission to access /dev/ttyUSB. I assume it is a permission problem, which occurs after the reboot. My user is called 'sam' and the default daemon user doesn't have the same rights as 'sam'.

Any idea, or hints?

Cheers!
Martin